# Is there any logic to implement two calendars at a time on a click using angular7?

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker

I am unable to implement two calendars at a same time on button click!.Is there any way ??I have got the references using Angular-JS. But I want the code to be in Angular 7 and on the click, both the two calendars should appear at a time so that I can choose start date in one calendar and end date in other.

[click here for Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuBxc.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What did you try so far to make this happen? Could you show your code and explain what's going wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please read through this page. It talks about how to ask questions in a format appropriate for this site.

Comment: Hello Merijn, I don't have any implementation code as of now. Just waiting for the reference. I have attached a screenshot in the description, I think it might help for the better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I always use ng bootstrap for those functionalities. Try it,
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview

Comment: Thanks, but I have checked and I  feel it is not the right  solution. Because if I want to select start date of this year with today's date and end date of for suppose 2026! I am unable to do that with the solution you provided.I want to separate calendars as mentioned in the Screen shot provided as link in above description. I hope this description gave you the detailed info.